# Using a G. 655 with a G. 652.D fiber cable?

Tags: networking, fiber

Is it possible to use a G.652.D patch cord with a G.655 fiber cable for just a small distance (less than 10 m) for the interconnect only (from the patch panel to the switch) ? If yes or no, what will happen ?

And for long distance, its not possible and it will not work, because of the IOR will be different right ? or because another thing ?

Best Regards

Comment: Might try the Network Engineering SE instead of here.